# make evaluates an expression differently than shell

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to check whether a copy of file present at address A is older than the original file present at address B. So for instance, consider a file named as `scratch` present in the same folder as the one which holds the `makefile`. Let the address for these files be `address_a/`. Now let there be another address, say `address_b/bin` where I wish to *install* `scratch`. However, I intend to perform the installation in 2 scenarios :

- `address_b/bin` doesn't contain `scratch`
- OR whenever the copy of `scratch` present in `address_b/bin` is older than the one present at `address_a/`.

In order to do this, I'm making use of the following shell command :

`[ address_b/bin/scratch -ot address_a/scratch ] && echo 1 || echo 0`

Now executing this command directly on terminal will result in 1 as the output. However, executing this command via the `makefile` results in 0 as the output. The recipe in which I've used this command looks like this :

```
.PHONY : install
INSTALL = install
source = scratch
destination = address_b/bin/

install : capture_status != [ $(destination) -ot $(source) ] && echo 1 || echo 0
install :
    @echo $(capture_status)
ifeq ($(capture_status), 1)
    $(INSTALL) $(source) $(destination)
else
    @echo 'Installation has already been done.'
endif
```

So, where exactly is the issue present?

Note : I'm using GNU Make 4.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.3

Comment: The main issue with this question lies with the expression : `[ $(destination) -ot $(source) ] && echo 1 || echo 0`. First of all, as pointed by Renaud Pacalet's answer below, instead of  `$(destination)`, it should be much more appropriate to use `$(destination)/$(source)`. And secondly, by default make uses `/bin/sh` as the shell, which evaluates the above expression differently than `/bin/bash`. The details of this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63643950/executing-file1-ot-file2-yields-different-results-in-make-and-shell?noredirect=1#comment112547508_63643950).

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that make's main role is to compare last modification times of target files and prerequisite files in order to decide if target files must be re-made or not? In your case the following does exactly what you want, I think, in a much more natural way:

```
.PHONY : install
INSTALL = install
source = scratch
destination = address_b/bin/

install: $(destination)/$(source)

$(destination)/$(source): $(source)
    $(INSTALL) $< $(dir $@)
```

In summary it says to make:

1. `install` is an alias for `$(destination)/$(source)`, not a real file.
2. `$(destination)/$(source)` depends on `$(source)`, that is, if `$(destination)/$(source)` is older than `$(source)` it must be re-made, else it is up-to-date.
3. If `$(destination)/$(source)` must be re-made (because it is older than `$(source)`), the shell command to execute is:

   ```
    $(INSTALL) $< $(dir $@)
   ```

`$<` is a make automatic variable that expands as the first prerequisite of the rule (`$(source)` in this case), `$@` expands as the target (`$(destination)/$(source)`) and `$(dir ...)` is a make function that returns the parent directory. The command is thus equivalent to:

```
    $(INSTALL) $(source) $(destination)
```

but more generic.

### EDIT 1 (add a custom message when installation not done)

If you want a specific message or action when `$(destination)/$(source)` is up-to-date you can pass an information from one rule to the other using an empty file (e.g. `.done`):

```
.PHONY : install
INSTALL = install
source = scratch
destination = address_b/bin/
DONE    := .done
MESSAGE := custom message

install: $(destination)/$(source)
   @[ -f $(DONE) ] && rm $(DONE) || echo "$(MESSAGE)"

$(destination)/$(source): $(source)
    $(INSTALL) $< $(dir $@)
    @touch $(DONE)
```

### EDIT 2 (add an explanation of observed behavior)

The problem you observe is due to when make does what. The `ifeq` conditionals are evaluated by make when it parses the Makefile while the target-specific variables are expanded later, when it is too late to change the conditions of conditionals... Demonstration:

```
$ cat Makefile
.PHONY: c

c: foo := bar

c:
ifeq ($(foo),bar)
    @echo "foo = bar and foo = $(foo)"
else
    @echo "foo != bar and foo = $(foo)"
endif
$ make c
foo != bar and foo = bar
```

### EDIT 3 (make `if` conditionals and shell conditionals)

The two other solutions below are not my favorite at all because using the shell instead of make to test if a file is older than another offends my sensibility (and I am sensitive). They are here just for information.

GNU make has other conditionals, like the `$(if ...)` function, that you could use the way you want because they are expanded only just before make passes the recipe to the shell, after target-specific variables have been expanded.

Note: As `$(if ...)` tests emptiness, I modified the way `capture_status` is assigned such that its value is 1 or the empty string instead of 1 or 0.

Note: I replaced `$(destination)` in your test by `$(destination)/$(source)` because your original version does not work, I think: directory modification times are different from files modification times.

```
.PHONY : install
INSTALL = install
source = scratch
destination = address_b/bin/

install : capture_status != [ $(destination)/$(source) -ot $(source) ] && echo 1
install :
    @echo $(capture_status)
    $(if $(capture_status),$(INSTALL) $(source) $(destination),@echo 'Installation has already been done.')
```

But shell conditionals would work almost the same:

```
.PHONY : install
INSTALL = install
source = scratch
destination = address_b/bin/

install : capture_status != [ $(destination)/$(source) -ot $(source) ] && echo 1 || echo 0
install :
    @echo $(capture_status)
    @if [ $(capture_status) -eq 1 ]; then \
        echo "$(INSTALL) $(source) $(destination)"; \
        $(INSTALL) $(source) $(destination); \
    else \
        echo 'Installation has already been done.'; \
    fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the method explained in your answer is something I'm trying to avoid. Why? Because I wish to give a custom message if the installation is already done. Through your method, the default `*is up to date` message is printed if the installation is already done. Hence, I chose the method present in my question.

Comment: The thing is, I've set this method as my last approach if I cannot resolve my issue. However I intend to resolve this issue first, because it's not just about the updation of files but also about usage of shell commands in make. If I can't actually understand what lead to this issue, then I may stumble upon the same or similar issue in near future and at that time too I'll feel just as confused as I am now.

Comment: OK, let's try to understand your problem. But first, have a look maybe at my last edit to the answer, it suggests another solution.

Comment: Yes, this alternative method is good. Didn't know I could handle events in this way too.

Comment: Good. Have a look at my second edit for an explanation of what you observed.

Comment: So to summarize, you wish to say that my make code doesn't follow the sequence in which I've written it, during it's execution. Now I replicated your code and performed sample check using target specific variables and global variables. Then the difference in results became clear. However, making use of global variables in my case still doesn't resolve my issue.

Comment: _my make code doesn't follow the sequence in which I've written it_ Yes, but it is not a special case at all. Makefiles are not shell scripts, make never follows the sequence of statements in your Makefile. The order sometimes matters but in many cases it does not. _making use of global variables in my case still doesn't resolve my issue_: and what about the other solution I suggested with a dummy empty file to pass information from one rule to another?

Comment: The dummy file method (the one which used DONE variable) works, but unfortunately it doesn't display the custom message, if the installation is already done. The 2 methods mentioned by you in your 3rd edit fail to work. Both of them display 'Installation already done', regardless of the presence of `scratch` file at `address_b/bin/` address.

Comment: _The dummy file method (the one which used DONE variable) works, but unfortunately it doesn't display the custom message, if the installation is already done_: I do not understand how this is possible. Either the file exists or not. If it exists it means that the installation was needed and has been made. Else the message is printed. I suspect some typo. Let's continue this discussion in the chat such that you can show me exactly what you wrote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220616/discussion-between-renaud-pacalet-and-argon).