# Executing [ FILE1 -ot FILE2 ] yields different results in make and shell

Tags: makefile

From [Table 7-1 of Bash Guide for Beginners](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html), we can say that `[ FILE1 -ot FILE2 ]` will yield *True* if `FILE1` is older than `FILE2`, or if `FILE2` exists and `FILE1` does not. Executing this command on shell returns *True* if `FILE1` is absent and `FILE2` is present. However, when I made use of this in my make script, it yielded *False* whenever `FILE1` was absent and `FILE2` was present. To be precise, I made use of the following command in my make and shell scripts:

`[ FILE1 -ot FILE2 ] && echo 1 || echo 0`

Running this command on shell returned 1 whenever it was expected to. However, running this command via make resulted in 1 only when `FILE1` existed and was found to be older than `FILE2`. In other scenarios, i.e. whenever `FILE1` was not found to be older than `FILE2` OR whenever `FILE1` was absent and `FILE2` existed, the above command yielded 0 in my make script. Note that in my make script, I'm storing the results of the above command in a global variable. This global variable is later used in one of the recipes by a conditional.

So, I wish to know whether this is a bug/feature in make OR a possible issue from my end(due to some typo or other possible sources of error)?

Note : I'm using GNU Make 4.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.3

Comment: The shell make uses by default is not bash. This could maybe explain the difference you observe. You should create a very simple minimal example with known files and hard-wired file names in the Makefile such that everybody can reproduce what you observe.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, with GNU make 3.81, GNU make 4.3, the bourne shell and bash (4 tests). There is probably a bug in your Makefile.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I *could* reproduce running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS - using the default make version. I think you where on the right track though - there is def a diff between sh and bash

Comment: @code_fodder Very interesting, can you please add details (versions, Makefile...)?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, GNU Make 4.1, GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu). Did you try the experiment below? - would be interesting to see if you have a difference? - if you do then you can try to change the default SHELL in your makefile to see if that makes a difference - just out of curiosity more then anything :)

Comment: @code_fodder I tried your two shell scripts with bash 5.0.17(1)-release and bash 3.2.57(1)-release invoked as bash or sh (I do not have a real vanilla bourne shell). Both return `file1 older` if `file2` exists and `file1` does not exist. No difference but the opposite result of yours. I am very surprised. Did you run your experiments with a `file2` and no `file1`?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet oh wait I was doing file1 does not exist and file2 does exist (yes using files called `file1` and `file2`). So there *is* a difference. I repeated the test for when file1 does exist and file2 does not and in both cases file2 is older... so conclusion is that there *is* a difference between sh and bash, but I am seeing a different difference :o

Comment: You might want to avoid the use of `[` here as `-ot` is not POSIX shell compliant.  It's probably better to call `/bin/test` directly so as not to get a shell's built-in version.

Comment: Anyway, using the shell, in a Makefile, to test if a file is older than another is rather... strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this experiment (in a script):

In the case I tested: when file1 does not exist and when file2 does exist:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ file1 -ot file2 ] && echo "file1 older" || echo "file2 older"
```

yields file2 older

```
#!/bin/bash

[ file1 -ot file2 ] && echo "file1 older" || echo "file2 older"
```

yields file1 older

By default make will use #!/bin/sh as the shell, you can change this by: `SHELL = /bin/bash` in your makefile

I am not sure why this is different - its just a different implementation between sh and bash...

Comment: "I am not sure why this is different - its just a different implementation between sh and bash…" likely, `-ot` is not part of POSIX test so different shells (or binaries) can have different behaviour. IIRC Ubuntu's `/bin/sh` is dash, and Dash's `-ot` is "True if file1 and file2 exist and file1 is older than file2."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It differs in my case too. bash and sh behave similarly, if `file1` exists. However, when `file1` is absent, then the difference between them pops up.

Comment: @Argon this seems to be a difference between Bash (and apparently GNU Test?) and everyone else: Ubuntu's `sh` is `dash` which [according to its documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dash) matches zsh and bsd test: `-ot` is true if both files exist and file1 is older than file2.